# Is there a way to use (JAX-RS) Jersey reflection api to access methods given a path as an argument?

Tags: java, rest, reflection, annotations, jersey

Jersey must handle internal mappings to resources such that if given a url (/root/my/resource) will call the appropriate class/method annotated to handle the request. I have been searching the api looking for a way to get a class instance (and the correct method) that a given path points to. Is this possible?

For example:

```
Class<?> clazz = SomeJerseyMethodToGetClass('/root/my/resource');
```

I found something similar in this post: [Find a list of all Jersey resource methods in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484350/find-a-list-of-all-jersey-resource-methods-in-my-app) but in this case, I would need to know the handling class beforehand. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.